# Best way to track views and time spent per post in a listview, Flutter

Tags: flutter, optimization

I have a listview where I have multiple post widgets, I need to track number of views and time spent seeing each post

One naive approach i though of is to wrap post widget with a `VisibilityDetector` and make whenever user sees the post we increase the count, what will be the most optimized solution for this, which allows me to make minimal number of calls to backend?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the calls to the backend it doesn't matter what the method you are using you can visibility detector or whatever you want.

But send count to the backend when view is destroyed or else view is not the screen like when user put app in the ram there will be a callback that time just update count in the backend so that you can reduce the backend calls